# How to show Euler’s Product?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, zeta-functions, euler-product

Calling $P$ the set of prime numbers, Euler proved that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{n^s}=\zeta (s)=\prod_{p\in P} \frac 1{1-\frac 1{p^s}}$$
At University my professor proved that in this way:

- First we can see $$\frac 1{1-\frac 1{p^s}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \left(\frac 1{p^s}\right)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{p^{ks}}$$
- Then $$\prod_{p\in P} \frac 1{1-\frac 1{p^s}}= \prod_{p\in P} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{p^{ks}}$$
- So we see that when we calculate the product of the sums we obtain a sum of reciprocal of $s$-th powers of natural numbers, and for all $s$-th power of a natural number then it’s reciprocal is in the sum... so we conclude thesis.

This demonstration is surely clear but it appears to me a bit “informal” at the moment of the conclusions... Does anyone know a different demonstration of this Identity?

Comment: It is based on the existence of a unique decomposition of any number into a product of primary numbers (i.e., powers of prime numbers) (each one being at the power $s$).

Comment: Yes, it si clear, but i wa searching the same for another way... @JeanMarie

Comment: tl;dr use finite products and justify manipulations with absolute convergence.

Comment: Ok, thanks you!